# Can't stop a script that starts on bootup

Tags: raspberry-pi

I just followed these instructions to run a script on start up: 
http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html

I have to admit that I missed out the comments at the top of the file at: 
/etc/init.d/NameOfYourScript

When I boot it up it successfully runs the script, and I see the output on the command line. The trouble is, I can't log in to stop it, and ctrl C doesn't stop it. I also had x window setup, and I can't get into it that way either.

Am I locked out?

Comment: Plug the SD card into a computer and edit the file.

Comment: Ah, great idea! I don't seem to be able to mount the disk though, I've just tried on Mac and Ubuntu, is there a special trick?

Comment: In Ubuntu, you should be able to mount it just fine. What happens when you try mounting it?

Comment: Unable to mount 16 GB File system - Error mounting: mount: block device /dev/sde2 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: Dodgy SD card connector was making life hard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page linked above describes a way to run script when the Pi boots up. However, it is only appropriate for scripts which terminate without user input.

Installing the Upstart package appears to be the best solution:
http://infovore.org/archives/2013/08/09/running-scripts-on-startup-with-your-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

According to the site you just need to type: sudo /etc/init.d/NameOfYourScript stop in order to stop it. However, it will start every time you boot up unless you unregister it.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no where to do this, instead I just see the output of the script... ie. there is no command prompty

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem i was locked out,

### Solution:

1. close the pi
2. remove the sd card
3. then open the sd card on another linux based (ubuntu recommended) pc
   (windows will not work)
4. open the terminal on the linux pc (make sure you are logged in as
   root)
5. change directory to the cron job file called root  ,open it using
   nano and comment out or delete the code.

the cron job file will be located in /var/spool/cron/crontabs

and the /var will be inside the /media because its in a sd card not the os /var